# Подключение к fdb

Tags: python, база-данных

Имеется `.FDB` файл. Имеется скрипт:

```
import fdb

con = fdb.connect(dsn='localhost:/db.FDB', user='sysdba', password='pass')

cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
row = cursor.fetchall()
print(row)
```

При запуске появляется следующая ошибка: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "connect_db.py", line 4, in <module>
    con = fdb.connect(dsn='localhost:/db.FDB', user='sysdba', password='pass')
  File "/home/paranoid/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fdb/fbcore.py", line 734, in connect
    "Error while connecting to database:")
fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError: ('Error while connecting to database:\n- SQLCODE: -902\n- Unable to complete network request to host "localhost".\n- Failed to establish a connection.', -902, 335544721)`

Перечитал документацию, пробовал разные вариации сервернейма
ничего не помогает

Comment: `db.FDB` находится в папке с скриптом? Если да, то попробуйте: `con = fdb.connect(dsn='db.FDB', user='sysdba', password='pass')`

Comment: Да, находится.
Пробовал такой вариант, все равно ошибка

Comment: А файл БД точно лежит в корне тома? какого, кстати, может, есть смысл указать явно...

Comment: указывал точный путь, тот же результат

Comment: укажите полный путь к файлу без `localhost` и если не получается -
 приведите сообщение об ошибке...

Comment: @MaxU ` File "connect_db.py", line 4, in <module>
    con =fdb.connect(dsn='db.FDB', user='sysdba', password='masterkey')
  File "/home/paranoid/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fdb/fbcore.py", line 734, in connect
    "Error while connecting to database:")
fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError: ('Error while connecting to database:\n- SQLCODE: -902\n- Unable to complete network request to host "localhost".\n- Failed to establish a connection.', -902, 335544721)
`

Comment: @MilkiweedGtlt, вы указали не полный путь... В какой директории лежит этот файл?

Comment: @MaxU Рядом со скриптом, в той же папке

Comment: @MilkiweedGtlt, так вы уже попробовали указать __полный__ путь? что получилось?

Comment: @MaxU Да, пробовал. Точно такая же ошибка получается

Comment: @MilkiweedGtlt, хммм... а вы можете открыть данный файл не из Python? У вас пароль правильный?

Comment: @MaxU а вот насчет пароля не уверен